# How can I change my login screen resolution when connected to my monitor (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, login, resolution, monitor, lightdm

I have my laptop connected to a monitor via VGA. When I start the computer up, the login screen shows on both the monitor and laptop screens, and is not the correct resolution. I would like it to show up only on the monitor screen, and to be 1920x1080. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your multi-monitor system to boot up with a spanned desktop rather than each output being a mirror of the others, you will need to configure the X server manually.  You can do this with a fairly minimal `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.  For example, on my system it consists of only:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "ATI Technologies Inc Juniper [Radeon HD 5700 Series]"
        Driver          "ati"
        Option          "monitor-HDMI-0" "DELL U2311H [1]"
        Option          "monitor-DVI-1"  "DELL U2311H [2]"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "DELL U2311H [1]"
        Option          "LeftOf"        "DVI-1"
        Option          "Primary"       "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "DELL U2311H [2]"
EndSection
```

This configures the two screens to span with the one connected to the `HDMI-0` output as the primary and left of the output connected to `DVI-1`.  With this video card/monitor combination the resolution gets detected correctly.  If the best mode is not automatically picked, you might need to specify the `PreferredMode` option in the relevant monitor section.

Full documentation can be found in the `xorg.conf` manual page.

Comment: I haven’t tried it, but in an Ubuntu 12.04 review I read that you should now be able to configure a spanned desktop from the configuration screen UI.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really cool little program that helps with this it called "lxrandr"

Install from the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I tried it to no avail. When I boot up the login screen still shows on both with the incorrect resolution.